# Ищу аналог HttpSessionStateBase в .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mvc

Переношу чужую бэкенд-библиотеку на WebAPI. В коде одного из контроллеров столкнулся с тем, что System.Web.Mvc.Session в NET Core отсутствует. А он нужен. Как я могу получить информацию о текущей сессии? Заранее спасибо.

Код, где возникла проблема. Там Session - как раз экземпляр HttpSessionStateBase

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает представление для страницы "пояснения"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="code">код для которого необходимо получить представление</param>
    /// <returns>представление</returns>
    public ActionResult Index(string code)
    {
        using (SessionConnection sessionConnection = SessionConnection.Connect())
        {
            if (!sessionConnection.Check())
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 500;
                return View("~/Views/Error/InternalError");
            }

            ViewData["SessionID"] = Session.SessionID;
            ViewData["IsActive"] = sessionConnection.IsAuthorized(Session.SessionID);
            ViewData["passedCode"] = code;

            sessionConnection.UpdateSession(Session.SessionID, Settings.SessionTimeout);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) && code.Length >= 2)
            {
                string code2 = code.Substring(0, 2);
                ViewData["data-group"] = code2;

                using (SessionManager sessionManager = SessionManager.Connect())
                {
                    if (!sessionManager.Check())
                    {
                        Response.StatusCode = 500;
                        return View("~/Views/Error/InternalError");
                    }

                    Dictionary<string, string> tree = sessionManager.TnvedRepository.LoadExpTree();

                    if (tree.TryGetValue(code2, out string value)) ViewData["data-section"] = value;
                    if (code.Length >= 4) ViewData["data-subgroup"] = code.Substring(0, 4);
                }
            }
        }

        ViewData["topNotification"] = HtmlParts.Parts.TopNotification;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: `HttpContext.Session`? [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: .NET Core 2.2 уже [снят с поддержки](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core), кстати.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо большое за ответ. HttpContext.Session оказался ровно тем, что надо. А что .NET Core 2.2 снят с поддержки, знаю. Но старший программист сказал пока на 5ый не переходить. Вроде как, слишком много чего перепиливать придётся, а проект в продакшне, так что не до того.

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 - ваш выбор, он LTS. .NET 5 можно пропустить, а потом выйтет .NET 6 LTS. Но 2.2 - странный выбор.

Comment: Не странный, просто видимо когда-то начали проект на 2.х, потом пошли на 2.2. Я так прыгал 2.0 -> 2.1 -> 2.2 -> 3.0 -> 3.1 и вот только недавно на пятёрку переполз половиной проектов, часть до сих пор на 3.1 находится.